# NGINX always redirects to localhost and port

Tags: redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an NGINX proxy server that reverse proxies a local NGINX server running on some port. I'm
wanting this to all be kept in the same domain to it looks seamless to visitors. Something like this

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.html ===> http://127.0.0.1:1280/bar.html
```

This works out just fine if I intentionally trigger a file not found error, example

```
http://example.com/foo/this-file-doesnt-really-exist-on-server.html
```

it goes through and stays at that address as expected. However if I navigate to a file that does exist such as

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.html
```

The browser is instead redirected to

```
http://127.0.0.1:1280/bar.html
```

and since that server is listening only to localhost the browser launches a Page Not Found (404) error

This baffles me, Ive tried everything, Ive scoured Google for over a week trying hundreds of solutions without any success or change at all, Iv tried dozens of combinations with these headers

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
```

and have tried dozens of different proxy reidrects including completely disabling proxy redirect

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:1285/ http://example.com/foo/;
```

or

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

I've about given up and deemed it entirely impossible in NGINX, if anyone has any help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For people who have found this by search (as I have), **setting the relevant headers are very important** (at least that was what fixed it for me)

Comment: `proxy_redirect off;` was the thing which worked for me after applying the recommendations in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for *proxy_pass*, not *proxy_redirect*:

```
location / {
    # include your proxy params
    # ...
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1280;
}
```

See the nginx docs on this:

- [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: Proxy pass is what I use, its just that it occasionally will redirect the browser to the proxied severs URL instead of continuing to reverse proxy it. ------- I think Ive found the problem to be caching, I had proxy caching enabled and after I disabled it I noticed a lot of odd quirks stopped such as that one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be caching. I had open file caching, fast cgi caching, proxy caching, and open log caching enabled. After disabling all of those the weird quirks likethe one mentioned here have so far stopped.